# Transformar string em hora no Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, mongodb, time

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em VueJS e em uma tela tenho dois input's de hora e estão sendo salvas no MongoDB como String.
Porém o input só aceita no formato de hora e quando clico na grid e os inputs são preenchidos com os dados do objeto em questão os campos de hora não são preenchidos pois estão no formato de String e precisam ser convertidos para o formato `time`.

Já pesquisei algo sobre isso mas encontrei somente funções que convertem data e hora juntos, nada que fosse somente conversão de hora.

Se alguém puder me dar um exemplo de como fazer essa conversão de String em hora eu agradeço...

Comment: Inclua em sua pergunta o código dos input's com suas máscaras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando a data atual mais a hora que você precisa:

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDay();

var hour = '12';
var min = '35';

var reserv = new Date(year,month,day,hour,min)
```

Se precisar utilizar timestamp:

```
reserv.getTime();
```